# font-size of the tree-view ecilpse in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

How can I change the font-size of the tree-view inside Package Explorer view on Eclipse Juno on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

On Juno and up you can adjust that font by CSS.

Lookup the files in `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.x.vy/css` for your current style sheet (probably `e4_default_gtk.css`), and then just add the following rule:

```
#org-eclipse-jdt-ui-PackageExplorer Tree,
#org-eclipse-ui-navigator-ProjectExplorer Tree {
  font-size: 10px; /* <-- Desired font size */
}
```

Pro tip: Next time you need to find the CSS Id for a part of the UI, use *CSS Spy* which you can open with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F5</kbd> (after you have installed it).

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

From Eclipse Luna(4.4)

Looks like the css files are no longer in old folder:

```
`eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.x.x.vy/css`,
```

they are moved to the new folder:

`eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_x.x.x.vxxxxx/css`

And you must select a theme to apply it, in the menu

`[Windows]==>[Prefrence]==>[General]==>[Appearance]`